# PhoneGap config.xml iOS app icon issues

Tags: android, ios, phonegap-build

*The PhoneGap docs say I can set this via config.xml (and this was true three months ago). I do not have an Apple machine so I cannot set the icon via Xcode...  so please avoid directing me to answers that require an Apple osx command line and share a config.xml solution if you know it - thanks*

I build my app on build.phonegap.com

- The build phonegap 'control panel' has my app icon
- The app icon appears on Android, but not on iOS.
- My iOS installation just shows me a black square with rounded
  corners.

Builds three months ago did app icons fine on both Android and Apple.

I have a flat directory structure. My index.html (my main jquery mobile app code), config.xml and icon.png are in the same directory.

Can anyone advise on where I am going wrong? My config.xml is shown below for reference... (thanks)

```
<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.myapp.app16"
        version   = "16.5.11">
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
    <!-- name, descriptiona and author tags omitted from here on purpose -->
    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="internalOnly" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" spec="1.0.3" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" spec="2.2.0" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" spec="1.2.1" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" spec="3.2.2" />
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" spec="2.1.3" />

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
        <string>100</string>
    </gap:config-file>
  <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon src="icon.png" />
    </platform>

    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon src="icon.png" /> <!-- Default icon -->
    </platform>

</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you actually need to add every different icon size that apple uses for each device.

This is my actual config.xml where I have my icons for android and ios.
Note that I have my icons on folders located as: **res/icon/ios** and **res/icon/android**

```
<!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
<!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
<!-- <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" /> -->
<!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
<!-- iOS 6.1 -->
<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-Small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-Small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />

<!-- Android Icons -->

<icon src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
```

Comment: My understanding is the *recommended* solution was to place platform specific settings within <platform> tags. Your suggested solution works, but differs. from the recommended. Since it works for you, I'll go with it. I'm just concerned that its an unwritten feature and thus that I'll find myself back seeking again in a couple of months. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That is correct, I haven't made the change myself because it still works. But you can(should) place them inside their platform tags respectively. `<platform name="android"></platform>` for example.